# Jersey web service and hibernate one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jersey, moxy

I am getting the `500 - Internal Server Error` from POSTMAN when I try to create new user using Jersey rest service. Can someone tell me what's the correct way to load and form the `JSON` for hibernate one-to-many mappings. I'm using `jersey-media-moxy` for `JSON` support.

In my code, I have my resource:

```
@Path("/users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    private UserService userService = new UserService();

    @POST
    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

My `UserService` is

```
public class UserService {

    public UserService() {
    }

    public User addUser(User user) {
        Object<User> newUser = new ObjectImpl<User>();
        return newUser.addObject(User.class, user);
    }
}
```

My entity model for user is

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.authenticate", query="from User u where u.userEmail=:email")
@Table(name="USER", schema="mastercard")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long userId;
    @Column(name="user_email", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String userEmail;
    private String password;
    @Column(updatable=false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp created;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp modified;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Collection<Favourite> favourite = new ArrayList<Favourite>();
}
```

The error trace is:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:951)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.algattas.savour.savour_rewards.model.User.favourite, could not initialize proxy - no Session]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:949)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.algattas.savour.savour_rewards.model.User.favourite, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CollectionContainerPolicy.iteratorFor(CollectionContainerPolicy.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:483)
    ... 48 more
```

When I read about this error, I found out that it happens because of trying to access a related table after the session is closed. However, I do not try access this related object anywhere in the code. My implementation of `addUser` is below:

```
@Override
    public T addObject(Class<T> entityClass, T newObject) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        long newObjectId = -1L;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            newObjectId  = (long) session.save(newObject);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return getObject(entityClass, newObjectId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is causing by this code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Collection<Favourite> favourite = new ArrayList<Favourite>();
```

Can you show your `Favourite` entity?
You should try `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemType", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` at `Favourite`.

Comment: Thanks, here I changed to eager loading and used `@XmlTransient` to remove it from the XML response.

Comment: Can you vote for this answer instead for "thanks". Give your example of using `@XmlTransient` and mark it as accepted answer. It will be usefull for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I can't accept your answer fully because I don't think Eager loading is a good option. Can you improve it to handle the problem of trying to eager load everything that can cause performance issues.